# Keeping track of multiple arraylists

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist

The issue I am having is showing up every now and then, and it's quite annoying.

I have two arraylists:
* One keeping track of names
* One keeping track of "counters" of how many times these names are used

The problem:
The counters "connected" to each name can be different. I want to select the 6 names with the lowest counters connected to them. How do i do this, while keeping the selection random if there are 7 or more names with the lowest counters connected to them?

For info:
The two arraylists are "connected" by being shuffled with the same random seed.
The reason they are shuffled at random is because for the first draw (5 draws - 1 for each day) everyone starts at count 0. By shuffling the arraylists I can make sure the selection is randomized.

I hope this makes sense to you. If my description is poorly worded or you have issues understanding something, ask away :)

Comment: It might be clearer if you included some code.

Comment: Instead of keeping related data in two separate objects, put it in one object. That's how object oriented programming works. Create a class that has a name field and a counter field, and make an array of instances of that class. You'll need a comparator and possibly `hashCode()` and `equals()` implementations, depending on the collections where you want to use it. But start from putting all related data together.

Comment: I will try to do this instead :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Simply don't use multiple arrays, use a class like `CountedName` which stores the name and the counter. Then you can simply sort the array of those `countedName`s by using a custom comparator which orders based on the stored `count`.

Comment: Ah, this makes a lot of sense. I will figure out how to try this :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than creating two separate arrays/list, you can maintain one hashmap storing names as key and counts as values and you can provide your customised logic to increment/decrements counters accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an object (a class) that contains the name and the counter as variables. You'll then store these object in one single array your can shuffle as you want.